# Connection error related to sql azure database instance

Tags: azure-sql

I use the azure sql database service, I try to connect to the server where I have hosted the database and in a specific network I can not connect, however, from other wifi networks if I can connect. perform a telnet to port 1433 and I do not respond. Another fact is that I already configured in the azure firewall the corresponding ip, I can ask the internet provider about it or is it a matter of lack of configuration on my part, I thank you in advance, the error is as follows:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
Cannot connect to server.database.windows.net.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured 
to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An error 
occurred during the connection attempt because the connected party did not 
respond properly after a period of time, or the established connection 
failed because the connected host was unable to respond). (Microsoft SQL 
Server, Error: 10060)

For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-10060-database-engine-error

An error occurred during the connection attempt because the connected party 
did not respond properly after a period of time, or an error occurred in the 
established connection because the connected host was unable to respond.
```

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Is this problem rectified ?? Looking for solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060` has probably nothing to do with networking.

The proof is that form ***some*** machine you can connect to that Azure SQL Database.

Probably for those machines where you cannot connect the port 1433 is closed.
Ensure that you enabled 1433 outbound on the Windows Firewall of the VM, as this will also not be permitted by default.

If you fire up SSMS from that machine it should ask you automatically to set that rule for you:

[image]